# Appium GRID. Identify device that does not run e2e tests

Tags: grid, appium

I have 3 available devices in Grid. Is it possible to get ONE of 3 devices that is not busy with e2e test?

Comment: What do you want to achieve doing so?

Comment: @SubanDhyako I want to run test on available device.